# Labels from an Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I need to make labels for files that show the student name and the AP class or classes they are in. I have the attached Excel sheet to work from but I can not figure out have to do this without manually typing them all.

[image: Spreadsheet of students info]

Comment: Here is what I need them to look like in the end.

Brockman, Liliane
11
AP English Language and Composition
AP Environmental Science
AP Psychology

Comment: What have you tried? A Google search turned up this walkthrough: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-print-mailing-labels-for-an-address-list-in-Excel-d9ae0b60-9fd0-4a90-9da9-0ec3a4b011b2

Comment: I have tried that but I have a possible 10 classes but some have 1 or 2 they are in.  It leaves a line for each field if I do it that way so the label would be huge with lots of empty space.  Also I need it to put the class name in for whatever class is marked with a 1.

Comment: So I guess a better way to explain it is that I need it to print the class title for any class with a 1 in the field.  A reg mail merge just show the one not the title of the class.

Comment: You need to make another sheet where you have only the ones with 1, and from there get the labels done

Comment: I have that but it till puts in all the blanks for any class the student is not taking. Is there a way to get rid of blanks when you merge it?

Comment: The problem is there are 689 students on the list so we are trying to not have to totally redo the whole thing.

Comment: Can you add an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use VBA user defined function `UDF`
Create a new module in Visual Basic Excel (Alt + F11, Insert Module) and copy the following to it:

> Public Function concatcell(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As
>   Range, RowNumber As Integer)
>     Dim i As Long
>     Dim J As Long
>   Dim Result As String
>     Result = ""
>       J =
>   LookupRange.Columns.Count
>        For i = 1 To J
>       If LookupRange.Cells(RowNumber, i) = Lookupvalue Then
>         Result = Result & LookupRange.Cells(1, i) & " "
>      End If
>   Next i
>     concatcell = Result
>     End Function

Now in a new column at the end of the Data of your file (after Ap World History in your example) write the following:

`=A2&" " &B2& " " &C2&" "&concatcell(1,$D$1:$AB2,ROW())`

$D$1:$AB2 is the range of the first 2 rows without Last Name (A), First Name(B) and Grade(C), the $ to fix some references and let the others to change when you drag the formula down
A2&B2&C2 to concatenate with the result of the UDF
You can drag the formula down without modifying anything it will change by itself
When finish copy the result column and `Paste Special Values` where you need the `Mail Merge Data`